# The entity type required a primary key to be defined - but there is

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I probably have a fairly trivial problem with EF configuring 1 table. This is how my class looks like:

```
public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modification Date")]
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
}
```

This is how dbContext looks like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base (options) { }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

And while creating migration I get this error:

> The entity type 'Task' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating' [...]

But as you can see I have an attribute [Key], the property is public and has a setter, what could be the problem?

Comment: are you generating the migration using visual studio? try rebuild(clean + build) the project and clear the cache, you code is fine and should work. Make sure that you are using `[Key]` from `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Comment: I tried via VS and CLI with the same result, I cleaned the project, even deleted .vs folder and still the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was the dumbest mistake in a long time. It turned out the context was using the Task system class instead of my model class...